# Remove duplicate values while group by in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

[given input data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ypR.png)

[Required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPbhG.png)

[I am able to achieve this using groupby fn as `df_ = (df.groupby("entity_label", sort=True)["entity_text"].apply(tuple).reset_index(name="entity_text"))`, but duplicates are still there in the output tuple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urW5w.png)

Comment: Adding data samples as code snippets and your desired output would help a lot :)

Comment: data samples added, pls review

Comment: Adding code snippets mean getting rid of images ;) @Sandeep Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SeriesGroupBy.unique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html) to get the unique values of `entity_text` before applying `tuple` to the list, as follows:

```
(df.groupby("entity_label", sort=False)["entity_text"]
   .unique()
   .apply(tuple)
   .reset_index(name="entity_text")
)
```

**Result:**

```
  entity_label                                                      entity_text
0    job_title  (Full Stack Developer, Senior Data Scientist, Python Developer)
1      country                                     (India, Malaysia, Australia)
```

Comment: great, u solved my long pending problem, hats off to you

Comment: @SandeepSingh  Pleased to help!  Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'entity_label':["job_title", "job_title","job_title","job_title", "country", "country", "country", "country", "country"],
'entity_text':["full stack developer", "senior data scientiest","python developer","python developer", "Inida", "Malaysia", "India", "Australia", "Australia"],})
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df['entity_text'] = df.groupby('entity_label')['entity_text'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
df.drop_duplicates().reset_index().drop(['index'], axis='columns')
```

output:

```
    entity_label    entity_text
0   job_title   full stack developer,senior data scientiest,py...
1   country     Inida,Malaysia,India,Australia
```